# What's the best way to add an image to a page?

Tags: media

I'm wondering if there's a standard, nice way to add a picture - icons for example - to a page. These images should be static (= non-changing), which means that they don't depend on something else (e.g. the user's gender). Let's say that I would like to create a table with two columns: in the first column comes some random text, a view or whatever and in the second column comes a picture, according to the caracteristics I set before. [Thus, to be completely clear, the image in the column on the right side is simply chosen by the site editor and doesn't change when the text in the left column is changed.]

How can I insert such an image? Is there a module that makes this possible? I can't find any... For icons, I now created a content type 'Icon' with field_image and an image style 'Icon' with 'Image styles'. These ones combined work pretty fine, but it doesn't seem a very clean way to achieve my goal, because I've to create a new content type for each icon. Or is it?

Comment: What you've done sounds perfectly reasonable as a Drupal way of doing things.

Comment: Agree with @Ben - I think your solution sound just fine.

Comment: Look at the "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)". First bullet: "every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”". If you want pictures in template, ask about template. If you want them in node's body, ask about node's body. And so on. If your question is not meant to be a pool, word it (**and it's title**) the way it will not *look* like a pool, but a question about defined real life case. Or you can always flag for moderator's attention, community makes mistakes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends a little on what you want to achieve. Is it a static set of icons that will never change? If so, you should consider just creating a block containing simple HTML for your images. That way, you can use this block wherever you want, and you can style both the images and the position of the block using CSS.

Strictly speaking, adding `field_image` to a content type implies a relationship between the image and the other content of nodes of that content type. I wouldn't advise creating a whole content type just to hold icon images.

Hope this helps!